# Why doesn't this client/server program stop?

Tags: java, swing, sockets

As I am learning java socket, I've made a functionnal but very simple chat in two frames : one client and one server. The app is only local and works. But it does not stop when I close windows (though I added WindowListener to both frame classes) : what's wrong ?

Don't forget to run the server first, and then the client : both frames will be visibles only after the client connection.

Here is SimpleSocketFrame.java (base class for both frames) :

```
package com.loloof64.java_se.simple_socket;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public abstract class SimpleSocketFrame extends JFrame {

    public SimpleSocketFrame() {
        setTitle(getFrameTitle());
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

         messageToAddField = new JTextField(30);
     messageToAddField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                    if ( ! messageToAddField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                        addMessage(messageToAddField.getText());
                        messageToAddField.setText("");
                    }
                }
            }

    });

        printedMessagesArea = new JTextArea(10,30);
        printedMessagesArea.setEditable(false);

        add(messageToAddField);
        add(printedMessagesArea);

    pack();
}

protected abstract void addMessage(String s);
protected abstract String getFrameTitle();

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5861605385948623162L;
protected JTextArea printedMessagesArea;
private JTextField messageToAddField;

}
```

Here is the server app class : SimpleSocketServer.java

```
package com.loloof64.java_se.simple_socket;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SimpleSocketServer extends SimpleSocketFrame {

    public SimpleSocketServer(){
        super();
        setTitle("Simple Server");
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
            relatedSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            outStream = new PrintStream(relatedSocket.getOutputStream());
            isr = new InputStreamReader(relatedSocket.getInputStream());
            inStream = new BufferedReader(isr);

            final InStreamRunnable inStreamRunnable = new InStreamRunnable();
            Thread inStreamReaderThread = new Thread(inStreamRunnable);



            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
                    try {
                        inStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                    isr.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    outStream.close();
                try {
                    relatedSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                try {
                    serverSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    inStreamRunnable.stop();
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            });

            inStreamReaderThread.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Could not create the server !!!",
                    "Fatal error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class InStreamRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (weMustGoOn){
                String line;
                try {
                    line = inStream.readLine();
                                   printedMessagesArea.setText(printedMessagesArea.getText()+line+"\n");
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            }
    }

        public void stop(){
            weMustGoOn = false;
        }

        private boolean weMustGoOn = true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void addMessage(String s) {
        s = "Serveur> "+s;
        outStream.println(s);
        printedMessagesArea.setText(printedMessagesArea.getText()+"Client> "+s+"\n");
    }

    @Override
    protected String getFrameTitle() {
        return "Simple Server";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleSocketServer().setVisible(true);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4288994465786972478L;
    private Socket relatedSocket;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private PrintStream outStream;
    private InputStreamReader isr;
    private BufferedReader inStream;
 }
```

Here is the client class : SimpleSocketClient.java

```
package com.loloof64.java_se.simple_socket;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter; 
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SimpleSocketClient extends SimpleSocketFrame {

    public SimpleSocketClient(){
        try {
            socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 12345);
            outStream = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            inStream = new BufferedReader(isr); 

            final InStreamRunnable inStreamRunnable = new InStreamRunnable();
        Thread inStreamReaderThread = new Thread(inStreamRunnable);

            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
                try {
                        inStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    isr.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                outStream.close();
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                inStreamRunnable.stop();
                System.exit(0);
            }

        });
            inStreamReaderThread.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Could not create the client !!!",
                    "Fatal error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleSocketClient().setVisible(true);
    }

private class InStreamRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
            while (weMustGoOn){
            String line;
            try {
                line = inStream.readLine();
                      printedMessagesArea.setText(printedMessagesArea.getText()+line+"\n");
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            }
        }

    public void stop(){
        weMustGoOn = false;
    }

    private boolean weMustGoOn = true;

    } 

@Override
protected void addMessage(String s) {
    s = "Client> "+s;
    outStream.println(s);
    printedMessagesArea.setText(printedMessagesArea.getText()+s+"\n");
}

@Override
    protected String getFrameTitle() {
    return "Simple Client";
}

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5468568598525947366L;
    private Socket socket;
    private PrintStream outStream;
    private InputStreamReader isr;
    private BufferedReader inStream;


 }
```

Comment: Is it the same issue for both client and server?

Comment: Yes, both frames can't close.

Comment: The system won't exit while there are daemon threads running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program doesn't stop as you're attempting to close the network input `Readers` when closing a `JFrame`, which are blocking indefinitely. `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader` objects cannot close as the client thread is blocked in this `readLine` call which is waiting for a response from the server

```
line = inStream.readLine();
```

Comment out or remove:

```
inStream.close();
```

and

```
isr.close();
```

Just closing the `Socket` stream will suffice.

*Aside:* When interacting with Swing components for multi-threaded network applications, always use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). `SwingWorkers` are designed to interact correctly with Swing components.

Comment: That's work. Also, I'll replace the simple Threads with SwingWorkers.

Comment: Also, does it simply means that when I call isr.close(), I am waiting for acquring an unavailable lock ?

Comment: Rather you are waiting on a lock "semaphore" in `Reader` in `close` which is never notified as you're waiting for a response from the client/server. So effectively it's a deadlock situation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've understood. That's just a pity that Oracle documentation did not mention that in the Reader close() part. (I don't know if they did it elsewhere).

Comment: Yes, they did : not in their final example source, but at the bottom of the page, I quote "Multi threaded programs should close all Files and Sockets they use". But in official api documentation, they don't say that whe should not close InputStream in such situation.

Comment: It's actually your `readLine` statement that is blocked which prevents you from closing any of the `Readers`

Comment: Ok. So is it possible to stop the Worker Thread from blocking : I mean a kind of interrupt call ? Sorry, but multi-threading programming is a concept i still have to experiment.

Comment: I've tried cancel(true) on my SwingWorkers (as I replaced Threads with SwingWorkers), and closing both inputStream in client/Server : but it remained blocked.

Comment: Non-blocking sockets may be more appropriate although I haven't used them. See [here](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/09/04/nio.html) for more

Comment: Thanks : I'll read this article. But I also noticed, reading the Javadoc, that closing a socket, also close both its input and output streams. So I just need to close the socket.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `finally` block after `try` and `catch` to close the socket and after that you can close your program by system exit method.

Comment: Yes you're right : I've added finally clauses on the code of my computer.